# Custom UPI payment api?

Tags: webhooks, payment-gateway, upi

I would like to know if it's possible to create custom UPI api.
I want to know how to verify UPI transactions. I don't want to use any third party softwares.

I don't know. I am asking if there is some kind of api from NPCI. Or something. It will be great if someone could help with this.

I want to receive the UPI payment and verify the payments. Just like other payment gateways without using any third party payment gateways. I just need UPI nothing else.

I am aware of the api's provided by banks

Example:

- https://developer.icicibank.com
- https://developer.federalbank.co.in/fedbnkdev/dev/getting-started
- https://apihub.yonobusiness.sbi

Is there something by NPCI or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can invoke upi links with --

`upi://pay?pa=upiid@okhdfcbank&amp;pn=JOHN BRITAS AK &amp;cu=INR`

*Note*: I haven't tried out myself....

Comment: Thanks, but this was not my question. Appreciate you help.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33488794)